# Encrypting ServiceStack ServerEventsClient messaging

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, httpserver

I'm trying to secure messaging between my server and client while using ServerEventsClient. On my server I register the corresponding feature and create keys pair. The problem is within client - I can't create EncryptedClient from ServerEventsClient.

```
var client = new ServerEventsClient("http://localhost:1337/", "home")
{
    OnConnect = OnConnect,
    OnCommand = HandleIncomingCommand,
    OnMessage = HandleIncomingMessage,
    OnException = OnException,
    OnHeartbeat = OnHeartbeat
};

var publicKey = client.ServiceClient.Get(new GetPublicKey());
```

I can successfully get the key but there is no something like

```
client.GetEncryptedClient(publicKey);
```

or

```
client.ServiceCLient.GetEncryptedClient(publicKey);
```

Is there a way to secure my messaging at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack's [Encrypted Messaging Feature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Encrypted-Messaging) is limited to normal Request/Reply Services where the Request and Response DTO's are sent packaged within encrypted messages.

ServiceStack's [Server Events](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Server-Events) writes directly to the response Output stream i.e. without encryption. Since notifications are sent in the clear you'll need to limit them to sending notifications of just "ID" references to sensitive information that the Clients would then access with an Encrypted Client.